Need help for the IBM COBOL Program Status Clause
I need a function or procedure to retrieve a username, libraryname, modulename, etc. from the active running program. The IBM documentation tells me something about "program status structur"! i know such a structur from RPG.
How can i use COBOL Program status structur anlog zu RPG PSDS?

We are using System i operation System V7R5M0! I have as newbie declared a Datastructur like ibm dokumentation. I don't know how i get Data into die fields of the structur!
Code snipped:
   SPECIAL-NAMES. LOCAL-DATA IS LOCDATA        
                  DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA       
                  PROGRAM STATUS IS PSDS.      
 ...
structur
 * Programmdatenstruktur                           
  01  REDEFINES PSDS.                              
 *    Programmname                                 
      03  SDSPGMNM                     PIC X(10).  
 *    Bibliotheksname                              
      03  SDSLIBNM                     PIC X(10).  
 *    Modulname                                    
      03  SDSMODNM                     PIC X(10).  
 *    Statement nuber. *N if not availible         
      03  SDSSTATEN                    PIC X(10).  
 *    Optimization Level                           
      03  SDSOPTLVL                    PIC X(6). 
 *    Exception Message Identifier                 
      03  SDSEXCEPTM                   PIC X(7).   
 *    Job name                                     
      03  SDSJOBNM                     PIC X(10).  
 *    Job number                                   
      03  SDSJOBNBR                    PIC X(6).   
 *    Job type                                     
      03  SDSJOBTYPE                   PIC X(1).   
 *    User Profile running the program             
      03  SDSUSERP                     PIC X(10).    
....

Must I use an ACCEPT clause in COBOL to fill die structur field with data?

Which compiler?  Which operating system?

Related: How to use the PROGRAM STATUS clause in a COBOL program.

Page 94 of the linked manual.

I have moved the code for you and added a tag.

According to the documentation, the program status data struture for COBOL is updated when an error occurs. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=handling-program-status-structure
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                            
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.                           
     SPECIAL-NAMES.                                 
        PROGRAM STATUS IS PSDS.                     
     WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                       
      01  PSDS.                                     
          03  SDSPGMNM PIC X(10).                   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.                              
   BEGIN.                                           
     display "Pgmname before exception: " SDSPGMNM. 
     CALL "BADPGM"                                  
          ON EXCEPTION                              
          DISPLAY "Call error".                     
     display "Pgmname after exception: " SDSPGMNM.  
    STOP RUN.                                       

Output (my COBOL program is called PGMSTAT)
Pgmname before exception:        
Call error                       
Pgmname after exception: PGMSTAT 


Very fine, the program is now OK. I had only to initialize the Datastructur PSDS
(INITIALIZE PSDS.).
With initialization all datastructur fields can be accessed.
Thanks all for help!!

Thank you very much! i think i've understood the routines working!
